# How to assign pre-existing roles to users upon sign up in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, roles

First of all, I'm new in Rails, so I apologize if this is long. I'm creating a jobs-board like website where it will have two types of users: companies that will post the jobs and job-hunters who will be able to apply for them. Since it's a one-to-many relationship, I tried to follow instructions from Railscasts' Embedded Association: http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association where I did:

bash:

```
rails generate migration add_role_to_users role:string
rake db:migrate
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  ROLES = %w[admin company user]

  def role_symbols
    [role.to_sym]
  end
end
```

users/new.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :role %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
</p>
```

For some reason f.collection_select is not adding the role to the role's column in the User table. When I go to the Rails console, the newly created user is there but role is "nil". I tried to use Rolify gem but it didn't give much instructions in how to add pre stablished roles using a form. My other thought is, if I create a Roles model and add the roles there manually wouldn't all the record(roles) be deleted when I upload in production? So, my question is:

Am I doing something wrong with f.collection_select? or is there a better way to accomplish this (without creating a table)? or just a better way?

Comment: are you permitting the :role parameter in your controller? http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: also, check out enums as a way to represent the users.role values: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Yes, I needed to permit the :role in the controller, but since I'm using devise, things are a bit different which is what I didn't know. So here it is:

controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
  end
end
```